# Meteor AutoForm preselect value in select with label/value

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm using Meteor v1.1.6 and AutoForm v5.4.0 to display a select input field with options generated by a helper.

```
{{> afFieldInput name="eventType" options=getEventTypes type="select"}}

var mapEventType = function (eventType) {
    return {
        label: eventType.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + eventType.slice(1).toLowerCase(),
        value: eventType
    };
};

EVENT_TYPES = ['TEXT', 'GOAL'];

Template.addEvent.helpers({
    getEventTypes: function () {
        return [EVENT_TYPES].map(mapEventType);
    }
});
```

I'd like to know, how I'm able to preselect a value for the select input field.

The background is, that in some situations there is only **one possible value** but the field "eventType" isn't optional, so I'd like to preselect the single possible value so that the user doesn't have to select the obvious choice.

I've already tried setting the type to "select-radio-inline", but the single choice isn't selected by default.

Comment: You can set a `defaultValue` for the `eventType` property in your simple schema, or set a `value` attribute in the `afFieldInput` tag. Either can be a function to dynamically set it if needed.

Comment: Hmm, setting the value attribute worked. I swear, I tried it but it didn't work. Maybe because I tried using a constant "value=EVENT_TYPE_GOAL" which didn't work, now I'm using a function returning this value. Thanks!